# Radio Frequency Counter

Tags: frequency

I'm starting a radio station and I need something that can count how many people are lisening. If there is show me the circut please. Thanks in advance

Comment: That requires magic, not electronics...

Comment: Lol serious please xD

Comment: That was serious.

Comment: Radio broadcasting is one-way -- it's not physically possible to determine whether there are any receivers.

Comment: Hmm ok unless the radio transmitts that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is absurd, there is no way to come up with a circuit to count how many people are listening to a radio station.

Comment: Rlly? How am I supposed to know this? It's a question for a reason.

Comment: Even if the receiver transmitted that it was tuned to your station,,you could have 10 people listening to the same radio, how would it know that?

Comment: Maybe the real underlying question is, how do Nielsen / Arbitron determine their broadcast programming ratings -- I think they send out survey questions and use statistical methods to estimate viewership / audience.

Comment: Just to be clear, the usual way to do this is to call a few hundred people in your broadcast area and ask them what radio station they're listening to.

Comment: You could build a circuit to detect the frequency of the receiver's local oscillator when the radio's tuned to your station, and have it call you on the phone once when it detects the LO and then once again when the LO drops out.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confused as to what a [frequency counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_counter) does, it's used to measure the specific frequency of a single signal so won't help you. You can refer to the question [Does a radio receiver add a load to the transmitter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-a-radio-receiver-add-a-load-to-the-transmitter) for a more detailed discussion of whether the load of a receiver affects the transmitter, but summary there is that it doesn't occur in the far field.

Assuming you're talking about a transmitter in the FM broadcast band it'll start the transition into far-field after only a few meters so unless the receivers are pretty much in the same room it won't be possible. The only way it would be possible is to say use a transceiver that also sent back information that it was "listening".